# Adding new values to plots that are created from pipes

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, pipeline

Consider the following data frame where we have data for 2 individuals (`ID` == `a` and `b`).

```r
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("a","b"), each = 500),
                   time = 1:500,
                val = rnorm(1000, mean=1, sd = 0.3))
```

We will subset the data for individual `b` and make a scatterplot of `val` vs `data_point` using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  filter(ID == "b")%>%
  mutate(data_point = c(1:500))%>%
  ggplot(.,)+
    geom_point(aes(x=data_point, y=val), size = 0.5)
```

[image]

Assuming this is time series data, we are interested in seeing how different moving average window sizes effect the value of the last data point in the scatter plot (`distance` == 500). Say we want to compare 3, 5, 7, and 10 point moving averages. We want to get the value of the last data point for each of these moving averages and add them to the scatterplot with a different color identifying which moving average the point belongs to. How can we do this inside a pipe (like is shown above), without having to create new objects to store the values of the moving average data points?

Comment: I struggle to understand why people sometimes get so attached to pipes that they will jump through hoops to avoid doing things any other way.  If you need to re-use the result of an intermediate step, then I recommend to  just assign it to an object and use that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in-pipe or stored as a variable. I'll store it as a variable in order to step through things, over to you if you want to keep it `%>%`-bound.

Reproducible data:

```r
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("a","b"), each = 500),
                   time = 1:500,
                   val = rnorm(1000, mean=1, sd = 0.3))
head(data)
#   ID time       val
# 1  a    1 1.4112875
# 2  a    2 0.8305905
# 3  a    3 1.1089385
# 4  a    4 1.1898588
# 5  a    5 1.1212805
# 6  a    6 0.9681626
```

A set of moving-average *functions*:

```r
funcs <- setNames(
  lapply(c(3, 5, 7, 10), function(wid) {
    function(x) zoo::rollapplyr(x, wid, mean, fill = NA)
  }),
  paste0("avg", c(3, 5, 7, 10)))
data2 <- data %>%
  filter(ID == "b") %>%
  mutate(data_point = 1:500) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(val), funcs)
head(data2)
#   ID time       val data_point      avg3     avg5 avg7 avg10
# 1  b    1 1.3087422          1        NA       NA   NA    NA
# 2  b    2 1.2744325          2        NA       NA   NA    NA
# 3  b    3 0.9992631          3 1.1941459       NA   NA    NA
# 4  b    4 1.0408029          4 1.1048328       NA   NA    NA
# 5  b    5 0.7839539          5 0.9413400 1.081439   NA    NA
# 6  b    6 0.9405627          6 0.9217732 1.007803   NA    NA
tail(data2)
#     ID time       val data_point      avg3      avg5     avg7    avg10
# 495  b  495 1.3165332        495 1.1744507 1.1142967 1.165816 1.263729
# 496  b  496 1.1748916        496 1.2697909 1.1034455 1.151561 1.243861
# 497  b  497 0.7040298        497 1.0651515 1.0804547 1.064344 1.208823
# 498  b  498 1.5053865        498 1.1281027 1.2037578 1.103806 1.154502
# 499  b  499 0.5899477        499 0.9331213 1.0581578 1.071087 1.086029
# 500  b  500 0.8700357        500 0.9884566 0.9688583 1.068396 1.041577
```

And a plot:

```r
# library(tidyr)
ggplot(data2, aes(x = data_point)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = val), size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(data = ~ tidyr::pivot_longer(tail(., n=1), starts_with("avg")),
             aes(y = value, color = name), size = 5)
```

I move the `x` aesthetic to `ggplot`, since it applies to all data, but kept `y=` within each geom. This method assumes that the data is ordered appropriately; if order is not assumed, then the `data=` subsetting will need to be adjusted.

[image: plot with last points highlighted]